# Magento 1.9 add new products to homepage with Layout update XML only

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd, layout-update, new-products

I manage to show 4 'new products' on my homepage. In my `Homepage > Design > Layout update XML` i put the following code:

```
<reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
            <action method="addPriceBlockType">
                <type>bundle</type>
                <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
                <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

I changed also the template path from:

```
template="catalog/product/new.phtml"
```

to

```
template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"
```

But is my code correct like this? Or do i have to change this also (and how?)?

```
template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"
```